# jqGrid contentType header not getting set

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, iis, jqgrid

```
   $("#liveRTMessages").jqGrid({
    url: $RT.ENDPOINT,
    datatype: "json",
    postData: { 'system': null },
    mtype: "POST",
    height: "100%",
    colNames: $RT.colNames,
    colModel: $RT.MessageModel,
    ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    gridview: true,
    loadBeforeSend: function (xhr) {


// for testing only 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $RT.ENDPOINT,
            data: {},
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf8',
            success: function (data) {
                var t = data;
            }
        });
    },
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {
        if (postData.searchField === undefined) postData.searchField = null;
        if (postData.searchString === undefined) postData.searchString = null;
        if (postData.searchOper === undefined) postData.searchOper = null;
        //if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: function (obj) { return obj.d.rows; },
        page: function (obj) { return obj.d.page; },
        total: function (obj) { return obj.d.total; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.d.records; }
    },
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        // future event handling, very last grid event thrown
    },
    loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
        return;
    }
});
```

I got jqGrid working fine for GET requests. However POST fails because I can't set contentType on http request. IIS expects 'application/json' as contentType for request. This works fine using $.ajax.

What's more interesting is that loadBeforeSend (above) is able to add contentType  request header.

I would like to be able to add application/json as a contentType when jqGrid makes a HTTP request in this case.

Really hoping that there is something I overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

I had jQuery.XDomainRequest library for cross domain requests which I had to remove to get this working. jqGrid works with contentType request header.